# Center aligned <li> with same height and width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery to sort letters in a word jumble game. I need the list items to display: inline and the  to be centered in their container. I also would like them to all be the same height and width (70px x 70px) so they look like scrabble tiles.

However the only way I can get them the same height and width is if I float them left. But then the  is not centered in the container. If I display them inline-block and adjust the padding, most of them look like squares but a letter like an "I" is not wide enough and doesn't look like a square.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="letters">
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">L</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">T</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="letters">
<ul id="sortable-2">
<li class="ui-state-default">K</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">I</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">H</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">T</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">G</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"> </div>

</div>
```

[Here's a link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3s3a8jq/1/)

Thank you for your help; I think this is a simple one but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` and give them both a width and a height of 70px. You can remove the padding since they will be vertically centered in the box by `line-height` and horizontally centered with `text-align: center`.

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mymrbzvg/

```
#sortable li, #sortable-2 li  { 
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; 
  display:inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#333;
  font-size: 36px; 
  line-height:70px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
  }
```

Comment: It looks like she also has some padding in those elements, which she can remove or set the content-sizing to border-box.

Comment: Yes I almost removed the padding, I will edit my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the padding adds to the total width and height.

Since you have a left and right padding on each letter block of 10px, that will add an additional 20px to the total width when a specific width is defined.

Simply remove the padding, specify the width and height and your blocks will display as squares.

```
#sortable li, #sortable-2 li  { 
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 70px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#333;
    font-size: 36px; 
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h3s3a8jq/2/

---

If you insist on having a padding value but you do not want the padding to add to the total width of the element, you can change the way this behaves by using the **box-sizing** property.

```
#sortable li, #sortable-2 li  { 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;        /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Please keep in mind that support for `box-sizing` [isn't fully supported by several browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing), so be sure to check to see if it works for your needs before implementing it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing